# PythonでNone判定をしてNoneでなければその変数をif分の中で処理するには

Tags: python

Pythonで以下のようなプログラムがあり、aaa(bbb)がNoneでなければaaa(bbb)の内容を表示させたいと思っていますが、aaa(bbb)の関数が2回呼ばれるが気持ち悪いと感じております。

例えば、if文の中でNone判定をしてNoneでなければ、ある値に結果を入れておいてif文の中でその変数を使って処理のようなことはできないのでしょうか。

もしくはもっと効率のいい方法でも結構です。ご存知の方、是非ご教示お願いします。

```
def aaa(bbb):
   if bbb == "ccc":
       return "ddd"
   return

if aaa(bbb) is not None:
   print aaa(bbb)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pythonでは、条件式の内部で代入を行えません。

公式チュートリアルの[データ構造のページ](https://docs.python.jp/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions)のには、以下のように書かれています。

> Python では、C 言語と違って、式の内部で代入を行えないので注意してください。 C 言語のプログラマは不満に思うかもしれませんが、この仕様は、 C 言語プログラムで遭遇する、式の中で == のつもりで = とタイプしてしまうといったありふれた問題を回避します。

そのため変数を使って書くのが一般的です。

```
a = aaa(bbb)
if a is not None:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

2019年にリリースされたPython 3.8以降では、`:=`オペレータを使用することで条件式中において代入を行うことが可能になりました。

- 参考記事：[Python3.8の新機能(2) - 代入式の導入 #Python - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ksato9700/items/d37efc6982365e24f6af)

したがって、次のように書くことができます：

```
def myfunc(s):
    if s == 'aaa':
        return 'some value'


def mytest(s):
    if (res := myfunc(s)) is not None:
        print(f'res is not None: {res=}')
    else:
        print('res is None')


mytest('aaa')  #=>res is not None: res='some value'
mytest('bbb')  #=>res is None
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonでは、一般的には以下の様に書きます。

```
ccc = aaa(bbb)
if ccc is not None:
   print ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

`x = aaa(bbb)` と同じ事ですけれども、python では関数オブジェクト(インスタンス)に属性値を持たせる事ができますので、以下の様にもできます。まぁ、参考までに、という事で…

```
import dis

def aaa(bbb):
  aaa.result = "ddd" if bbb == "ccc" else None
  return aaa.result

def main():
  if aaa("ccc") is not None:
    print aaa.result

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
  dis.dis(main)  

### Execute

8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (aaa)
            3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ccc')
            6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           12 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
           15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       29

9          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (aaa)
           21 LOAD_ATTR                2 (result)
           24 PRINT_ITEM          
           25 PRINT_NEWLINE       
           26 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 29)
      >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           32 RETURN_VALUE
```